# Bash Scripting: Writing/Adding text to an existing file

Tags: bash, scripts

So I'm trying to write a script that can add additional info an existing file and also prompt the user that info already exists in the file and that they can either write something else or exit.

```
#Enter the new info here
#Check to see if this info already exists
#If it does exit tell user to enter something else or give the option to exit back to main menu
#if doesn't, proceed input/add to the file
```

Here's what I've come up with so far

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

file=database.dat

echo "Enter a username:"
read $username
grep -q $username $file && echo $?
if [ $? == 0 ] ; then
        echo "User already exists"
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to elaborate more in your question if you're looking for more.  This should get you started.

```
#!/bin/bash

file=database.dat

echo "Enter a username:"
read username

grep -i "$username" "$file"

if [ $? == 0 ] ; then echo "User already exists"
 exit 1
else
 echo "$username" >> "$file"
fi
```

Here is the output...

```
ubuntu@ubuntu-xenial:~/t2$ ./test.sh 
Enter a username:
myname
ubuntu@ubuntu-xenial:~/t2$ ./test.sh 
Enter a username:
myname
myname
User already exists
ubuntu@ubuntu-xenial:~/t2$
```

Comment: Thanks this helped me get started. Adding on to this, I'm wondering how I can give the user the option to either enter another username or exit by pressing "q" instead of quitting out right away when there was a match